# A concise way to generate an array of integers 1 to 100 in c#

Tags: c#

I am looking for a concise way to generate an array of integers 1 to 100 in c# , ie

```
        int[] values =  {1,2,3 ..., 100};
```

so that I can use the array in a foreach loop:

```
       foreach (var i in values)
        {
            // do whatever  
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use a `for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)` instead of the foreach?

Comment: For int should be faster. Is it also not already possible using System.Linq?

Comment: @M.Babcock -  Just curious, that's all. I have been doing it with a for loop till now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

There's probably not much point in me putting this - Oded's 18 votes (including my own +1) pretty much say it all, but just to point out that if you're then going to use the integers in the array, to produce something - let's say an object - then you can roll the whole thing up.

So, let's say you want some strings:

```
var strings = Enumerable.Range(1,100)
  .Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Gives you an array of strings.

Or perhaps a `MyWidget` that's produced from a method call, which uses the index for something:

```
var myWidgets = Enumerable.Range(1,100)
  .Select(i => ProduceMyWidget(i)).ToArray();
```

If the original `foreach` code block was more than one line of code - then you just use a `{}` block

```
var myWidgets = Enumerable.Range(1,100)
  .Select(i => {
    if(i == 57)
      return ProduceSpecial57Widget(i);
    else
      ProduceByWidget(i);
  }).ToArray();
```

Obviously this last example is a bit silly - but it illustrates often how a traditional `foreach` can be replaced with a `Select` plus `ToArray()` call.